# Proving that a holomorphic function has a constant Re part if certain conditions are fulfilled

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, computational-complexity

I must prove that a holomorphic function has a constant Re part if certain conditions are fulfilled.

We have that:

$f=u+iv$ is holomorphic in $D \subset C$, where C are all complex numbers. We have that $au+bv+c=0=>x=const.$ Prove it?

So I tried using Cauchy-Riemann:
$$u_{x}=v_{y}$$
$$u_{y}=-v_{x}$$
but these statements don't lead me anywhere because we want to make use of the non-derivent value of these functions so I tried relating it to our equation:
$$au+bv+c=0=>u_{x}=-\frac{b}{a} v_{x};u_{y}=-\frac{b}{a}v_{y}$$
and then when we relate the two things we have:
$$u_{x}=v_{y}=-\frac{-b}{a}$$
$$u_{y}=v_{x}=\frac{b}{a}v_{y}$$
And that is my dead end, can someone help me out here?

Comment: What do you mean by proving $x=constant$? What is $x$?

Comment: And what are $a, b, c$?

Comment: $f(z) $ is holomorphic. If $a Re(f(z)) + b Im(f(z))+c = 0$ then $a \frac{\partial Re(f(x+iy))}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial Im(f(x+iy))}{\partial x} =0$ and $a \frac{\partial Re(f(x+iy))}{\partial y}+b\frac{\partial Im(f(x+iy))}{\partial y}= 0$. Use the Cauchy-Riemann equation, you'll get $\frac{\partial f(x+iy))}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(x+iy)}{\partial y} = 0$